# When to use Package-Private or Protected

Tags: java

I have an understanding of the differences between package-private and protected. But, are the certain instances where one or the other is preferred? And if so can you provide an example.

Why not make all classes, methods, and variables protected within a package?

Comment: A package of classes denotes a possible certain about of interoperability or support.  The choice might be made to allow some functionality to only be exposed to the classes in the `package` as the functionality doesn't make sense outside of the package (or extension), but which provides support or functionality for the other classes in the package

Comment: *"Why not make all classes, methods, and variables protected?"* Because some should be `public`, some should be `private`, and some should be package-private. That's why we don't make them *all* `protected`.

Comment: Simple rule:  make everything as private as possible.  If no other class will use a field/method, make it private.  If no other package will use a field/method/class, make it package private.  Make a field/method protected only when you want to enable its use by subclasses.  Finally, if you expect any class in any package will need a field/method/class, make it public.  You *could* make everything public or protected, but you’re giving up some encapsulation (control over your class and its instances) by doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use protected whenever you think only classes that extend should have access. Use package private whenever you think only classes that are from the same package should have access. Honestly, I’ve only used package private for inner classes.

Comment: I have multiple packages implementing complex functionality where only a few classes are `public` and all the rest are package-private, e.g. intermediate classes needed for "internal" transformations and aggregations, classes that definitely shouldn't be *inner* classes, and making them static *nested* classes would just put too much logic in a single source file.